# Longest increasing subsequence after rearranging k subarrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-programming, subsequence

I require a way to find an increasing subsequence of a given array which consists of distinct natural numbers from 1 to n in some random manner, after rearranging exactly k subarrays(continuous elements). But elements within the subarray cannot be arranged. In a special case, if the array is sorted, you could leave it as it is.

I'm thinking of applying Longest Increasing Subsequence algo on (n-k+1) elements and arrange the remaining accordingly but it would be very far from being close to correct answer.

I'm not asking you to code but any reasonable explanation would be helpful to begin with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly does it mean to rearrange a subarray?

Comment: What is `N`? It looks like you've used `n` for the size of the array, so I don't know what `N` is supposed to be.

Comment: What's the significance of rearranging *exactly* `k` subarrays? If I want to rearrange fewer than `k`, can't I just perform the identity permutation on some of the remaining elements?

Comment: @Brian With rearranging a subarray, I meant selecting k groups of contiguous elements from the array, and then rearranging all the k group of contiguous elements in some order to get the increasing subsequence of maximum length.

Comment: So basically you are saying you need to divide the array up into `k` nonempty contiguous subarrays, and you are allowed to change the order of those subarrays relative to each other, but you can't rearrange elements within a single subarray? Is that it? What if the array is already 1, 2, ..., n? Can I do the "trivial permutation" on some arbitrarily selected decomposition?

Comment: But k could be very much less than n

Comment: Yes you are write, you can't rearrange specific elements within subarray. But you could do trivial permutation if the array is already sorted. I mean you can leave the array as it is if its already sorted

Comment: OK, great. Can you edit all these details into the question text? It would make it a lot easier for anyone else who comes across this question.

Comment: Okay, I am doing so. Please tell me how could you approach this problem.

Comment: If I figure it out, I'll write an answer. If not, at least the clarifications will make it easier for someone else to understand your question and solve it.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I updated the question